# Are potentially wiki-type questions accepted yet?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

As a relative beginning, I was going to attempt a hop taste test in order to get a better handle on the different hop types. I could ask for some 6-8 recommendations to use for such a test. However it is likely to produce lots of answers of different opinions. Would such a question be allowed?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't sound like a good fit for the Q&A format.

Community wiki posts are not meant to be used as polls. The problem is that the question as stated seems subjective.

Content like yours would be more appropriate in chat.

You may be able to find a way to make one or more good questions out of the concept, however.